# How to create databinding in code behind using the same object that is initiated in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code :

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
        Background="#FFDEDEDE" 
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
       WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Compression Test" Height="1080" Width="1920">


    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="vmMain"
         sampleCount="100" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="gridUI">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Height="100">

                <Border Background="#FF8986D3" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,30" >

                    <TextBlock Text="COMPRESSION TEST"  FontFamily="Sans-serif" FontSize="30" Foreground="#FFF9F9F9" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                </Border>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200" Height="1080">


                    <Label  FontSize="24" FontFamily="Sans-serif" FontWeight="Medium" Name="doc" Foreground="White" Background="#FFA39AD8" Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="43">Files</Label>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D4" BorderThickness="0.5" Grid.Row="3"></Border>


                    <StackPanel Name="sp_doc" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Name="sp_sample_button" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/413.png" Height="40" Width="40"  UseLayoutRounding="True"   MouseDown="sampleDropDown" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="up_arrow"/>
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/412.png" Height="40" Width="40"  UseLayoutRounding="True"   MouseDown="sampleDropDown" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="down_arrow" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <!--<Button x:Name="sss" Click="sampleDropDown">s</Button>-->
                            <Label FontSize="18" FontFamily="Sans-serif" FontWeight="Light" Name="sam" Foreground="White" Margin="10">Samples</Label>

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="sp_s">

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/413.png" Height="40" Width="40"  UseLayoutRounding="True"  RenderTransformOrigin="-0.,0.558" MouseDown="reportDropDown" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="up_arrow1"/>
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/412.png" Height="40" Width="40"  UseLayoutRounding="True"  Cursor="Hand" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="down_arrow1" Visibility="Collapsed" MouseDown="reportDropDown"/>
                            <!--<Button Click="reportDropDown">r</Button>-->
                            <Label FontFamily="Sans-serif" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="10">Reports</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="sp_r">

                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>




                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Width="1781">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFFDFDFD" Height="111">
                        <TextBox Name="sampleCount" Text="{Binding sampleCount, Source={StaticResource vmMain}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"></TextBox>
                        <Button Cursor="Hand"  Height="75" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}"  FontFamily="Sans-Serif" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Click="NewSample_Click" Content="+" Margin="20,0,0,0" Background="#FFACAABF" />

                        <StackPanel Margin="20,19,0,0">
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/file512.png" Height="75" Width="75"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="0,0,0,0"  MouseDown="CreateReport_Click" Cursor="Hand" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/play1.png" Height="75" Width="75"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="20,18,0,18"  MouseDown="CreateReport_Click" Cursor="Hand" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>

                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/1131.png" Height="75" Width="75"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="1340,0,0,0"  MouseDown="CreateReport_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                    <Frame x:Name="newSampleFrame" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="center" Width="934" Height="456" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="0.408,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Frame x:Name="reportFrame"  Content=""  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="842" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="595" Margin="0,100,0,0" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Frame x:Name="graphFrame"  Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="456"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="934" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </StackPanel>


            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ViewModel
{

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }
    private string[]  sampleName;
    private string _sampleCount;
    public Data obj2 = new Data();



    public string this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            return sampleName[pos];
        }

        set
        {
            sampleName[pos] = value;

        }

    }

   public string sampleCount
    {

        get
        {
            return _sampleCount;

        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _sampleCount)
            {

                _sampleCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("sampleCount");
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                obj2.sampleCount = value;
                SaveFile.saveFileMain(obj2);

            }
        }
    }

} 
}
```

And I have the following code that create a textblock whenever I click on the OK button :

window2.xaml.cs:

```
private void Ok_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow win = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        int i = 1;  // counter for the name of each new textblock
        string name = String.Concat("sample", i);

        // add textblok to the document list of new samples

        if (File_name.Text != "")
        {
            TextBlock sampleText = new TextBlock();


            sampleText.Text = File_name.Text;
            sampleText.FontSize = 14;
            sampleText.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Sans-serif");
            sampleText.FontWeight = FontWeights.DemiBold;
            sampleText.Margin = new Thickness(20,0,0,0);
            sampleText.Name = name;
            sampleText.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(test1);
            sampleText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

            //binding 

            Binding myBinding = new Binding();
            myBinding.Source =
            myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("sampleName");
            myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            sampleText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);


            Grid.SetColumn(sampleText, 0);

            win.sp_s.Children.Add(sampleText);

            // checking if the drop down of sample is already open, if so it will show the last textblock with pressing the arrow button.
            var textblockSample = win.sp_s.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (textblockSample.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            {
                sampleText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        i += 1;  // increasing the loop of names by 1
        this.Close();
    }
```

Is it possible to use the same object that is initiated in xaml (vmMain) as a source for binding the textblock (sample text) to sampleName property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you don't set `DataContext` of your `MainWindow` to `MainViewModel`.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="vmMain" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Or, you can even set `DataContext` via `MainWindow`'s code behind, which you don't seem to intent to not keep it untouched.

Then to set binding source:

```
myBinding.Source = this.DataContext;
```

In the case you refused to set the DataContext, you still can:

```
myBinding.Source = this.FindResource("vmMain") as MainViewModel;
```

Not sure if I managed to solve your problem.

### Edit

I just realised your binding is in `window2`. You should do this:

```
myBinding.Source = win.DataContext;
```

Similarly, `myBinding.Source = this.FindResource("vmMain") as MainViewModel;` should also be changed to `myBinding.Source = win.FindResource("vmMain") as MainViewModel;`.

This is provided you still have that `MainWindow win = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;` line there.

Comment: didn't work. 
I tried data context :  <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext> 
and set to binding source like this : 
myBinding.Source = win.DataContext;

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Do note that if you decide to do `<Window.DataContext> <vm:MainViewModel/> </Window.DataContext>`, then you are creating another instance of the `MainViewModel`. If you have done something that would trigger binding in the instance from `<Window.Resources>`, it is not going to reflect because they are **two different instances**.

Comment: I've changed the binding to sampleCount property. I know it does not work because it should print "test" and the value of the property as you can see in the code of the property of sampleCount. 
When I did that I removed `<Window.Resources>` code, so there is only one instance.

Comment: If you removed that you don't have `DataContext` again. Just use `<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="vmMain" />`.

Comment: Error: "The resource "vmMain" could not be resolved."

Comment: Did you put it above `<Window.Resources>`? Make sure it's below resources.

Comment: `<Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="vmMain"
         sampleCount="100" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="vmMain" />
    </Window.DataContext>`

Comment: At first I forgot to put <Window.Resources> after I put it the error disappeared. But, still nothing shows in the console output.

Comment: These are the changes I made : 
**MainWindow** 
 <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="vmMain" sampleCount="100" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="vmMain" />
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: **Window2** 

`Binding myBinding = new Binding();myBinding.Source = this.DataContext ;myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("sampleCount"); 
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; 
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged; 
sampleText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);`

Comment: Also, why do you use `this` in `myBinding.Source = this.DataContext;` the object is not in window2, it's in the MainWindow. 
I think you should use `myBinding.Source = win.DataContext;` But I tried it and it didn't work also.

Comment: still not working, as I told you before I've already used `win` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is the resources property:

```
myBinding.Source = Resources["vmMain"];
```

`Resource` allows you to access the XAML-defined (or otherwise) resources for the current object - the window.
You can also access the resources of any `FrameworkElement` in the same manner.

---

**EDIT:** I hadn't noted the fact that the vmMain was in a different class. With this in mind, no there is no way to reference that object directly  from Window2 as there may be multiple `MainWindow`s so you'd have to pick which `MainWindow` instance the vmMain should be taken from.
What you can do, however is create `vmMain` in your `Application` object (App.xaml). This would then share that object across all `FrameworkElement`s in your application. To access this you could use

```
myBinding.Source = Application.Currennt.Resources["vmMain"];
```

Comment: Can you be any more specific as to what about it didn't work?

Comment: I've changed myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("sampleName"). to myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("sampleCount").
If the binding is OK there should be "test and the value of the string printed in the console output, but nothing shows. 
Also, there are no errors.

Comment: Also, you should keep in mind that the vmMain object is declared in the MainWindow.xaml not in the window2.xaml. So, I don't think you can reference it like this : myBinding.Source = Resources["vmMain"];